# How to evenly space divs

Tags: html, css

So I have two buttons and I want them to be evenly spaced apart. I've spent hours looking for a solution, and couldn't find one so I would like some help. My code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Moocraft's Tic-Tac-Toe</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    .hv-center {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }
    
    .playerChoose {
      background: #0000ff;
      background: linear-gradient(#0000ff, #6b6bff);
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
      font: normal bold 24px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
  <div id="gameTypePick" style="" class="hv-center">
    <button id="randomPlayer" class="playerChoose">
   <h1>Random Person</h1>
  </button>
    <button id="friendPlayer" class="playerChoose">
   <h1>Friend</h1>
  </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the two buttons evenly spaced apart not matter the device size. If anyone can help me that would be great!

I've tried using flex space-between, percents, vertical height/width. Nothing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ignore the styling of `hv-center` and try these [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) properties:

```css
#gameTypePick {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* Equal gap between elements */
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment */
  height: 100vh; /* You can use height: 100% of the parent container */ 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Moocraft's Tic-Tac-Toe</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    .playerChoose {
      background: #0000ff;
      background: linear-gradient(#0000ff, #6b6bff);
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 8px 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
      font: normal bold 24px/1 "Calibri", sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center;">
  <div id="gameTypePick" style="" class="hv-center">
    <button id="randomPlayer" class="playerChoose"> 
      <h1>Random Person</h1>
    </button>
    <button id="friendPlayer" class="playerChoose">
      <h1>Friend</h1>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```